# Test state of fields of a class with several fields

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have a class with several, lets say 50, fields. This class has also a method that changes the state of all of the fields depending on some conditions.

I'm creating a unittest for that method. This test should assert that the state of all fields is the correct one depending on the given condition, so I need access to the fields from the test class.

Given that the fields are private because they make sense only within the class I have to find out a way to access them from the test class.

I only see 2 ways for it:

- Set all fields as protected (or package visibility)
- Generate 50 getters for all fields
- Create 50 delegating methods to get the state of those fields instead of the whole object

In a normal situation I would selected the last one (though I don't really like to change the interface just for testing reasons). But does it really make sense to write 50 new methods within my class just for testing? Wouldn't it be better in this case to set the fields as protected, since with so many methods the class would become unclear?

NOTE. Reflection is the last option I would like to use because I don't like to use it while testing: I don't like to have literals refering to fields because if the name of a field changes, the compiler doesn't advice me.

Comment: Generally speaking, unit tests should be testing externally-visible behaviour.  How does the state of your internal fields affect the public interface?

Comment: The externally-visible behavior is that those fields will be shown to the user (The behavior is not actually relevant for other classes) so I need to test whether my method is setting the fields in a proper state or not

Comment: Ok, that implies that there is a public interface.  You should be testing that.

Comment: yes, the public interface is my public method, namely the one I'd like to test. I am testing it and the way to test it is to check if the fields have a proper state after calling my public method

Comment: Usually, that's *not* the way to unit-test something.  You should be testing whether these changes are visible *through your public interface*.

Comment: I don't agree. Let's say I have a class with a field `a` and a method `x()` that changes the value of `a` but does nothing else. This `a` will be used later within other methods. Are you saying that I don't need to test the method `x()` just because it is not showing something? In that case how can I know if the method is really doing what it is meant to do?

Comment: You should be testing that calling `x()` has the desired effect on the behaviour of some other method `y()`.  A trivial example would be the following unit test: `@Test void test() { Foo foo = new Foo(); foo.setX(42); assertEquals(42, foo.getX()); }`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Your last comment is very good. If you have no public way to get the value it doesn't matter which value you have.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do those fields manifest themselves in terms of external behaviour ? That's what you should be testing.

It sounds like (currently) the fields are implementation-only. Your unit tests should be implementation-independent and you should be testing the behaviour of your unit (class) to external actions. If there's no discernable behavioural difference, then what *is there* to test ? Note that you could implement your fields in different ways (distinct fields, entries in a map etc.) and your test should be agnostic to this.

If you can plug in a class to observe those changes (and, say, reflect those change sin a GUI) then you should abstract that out to an interface such that you can plug a new test observer in. That can then perform the appropriate assertions (i.e. did it get called back upon a field change?)

Comment: I am not making behavioral-testing but state-testing. It only matters which is the state of my fields after calling the methods, therefore though there is no behavioral difference there's still a state-difference to be tested. This should be tested within this class because is the one that has the fields. The fields will be used later within the class for other things

Comment: @iberbeu: State doesn't matter.  It's the effect of that state on behaviour that matters.

Comment: And what if the new value doesn't imply a behavior but is just going to be shown in a widget or whereever? In that case no behavior could be tested. It is just a value

Comment: @iberbeu: If this class is responsible for setting a widget, really you need to test *that*, rather than what its own local state is.  I'm not an expert on GUI unit-testing; perhaps there's a way of injecting mock widgets for this purpose?

Comment: also true, why don't you create an answer containing all points we just discused so that I can accept it?

Comment: @iberbeu: This answer (i.e. Brian Agnew's answer) pretty much summarizes everything, I think ;)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can find a solution that suits you with [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/).

The class [PropertyUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html) could have de functionality you are looking for.

Comment: this should b a comment not an answer.